# How to close a browser context after multiple test is written in same file

Tags: typescript, browser, playwright

```
import { test, Page } from "@playwright/test";
let page: Page;

test('First Test', async({ browser })=>{
    page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log("Hello World");
})

test('2nd Test', async()=>{
    console.log("Hello World 2");
})
```

After printing Hello World 2, Browser must close

Comment: Tests should not depend on each other or run in a particular sequence. The normal approach is to use `async ({page}) =>` on every test. Playwright will open and close the browser for you. You generally don't need to manage the browser. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `inputValue` to check for the value

```
async function replace(page: Page) {
  const streetNumber = page.locator("id=streetNumber");
  if ((await streetNumber.inputValue() === "23")) {
    await streetNumber.fill("45");
  } else {
    await streetNumber.fill("23");
  }
}
```